# Cannot find/click any elements on Apple Pay view in UITest

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, applepay

I've been able to successfully run ApplePay in my UITests, but once the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController is displayed, none of the elements on that view are locatable and any attempt to select elements on the underlying application view result in an error "..... is not frontmost".

Has anyone else encountered this problem and/or have any idea how to work around it?

Answer (score 3):

The Apple Pay UI is presented out of process (even though you trigger it with a `UIViewController` subclass), so I don't think you'll be able to pick it up with UI testing. It's presented out of process so that an app can't modify or manipulate the Apple Pay views.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit tricky, but here is how you can do this:

```
// create passbook app
let applePay = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.PassbookUIService")

// wait for an auth controller to appear
_ = applePay.wait(for: .runningForeground, timeout: 5)

// tap pay button
applePay.buttons["Pay with Passcode"].tap()
```

After that authorization will succeed and you'll get apple pay data.

But there is "one more thing" - **data will be empty on simulator**, so if you try to serialize it, you'll get an error. So I used data mock for simulator:

```
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
     print("WARNING! SIMULATING APPLE PAY!")
     let payObject = [String: Any]()
#else
     let payObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: encryptedData, options: [])
#endif
// send payObject to server
```

Answer (score 1):

UI Testing cannot interact with anything outside of your application. In your scenario, the framework can no longer do anything once your app presents the Apple Pay view.

To verify this, try printing out the app's hierarchy once the view appears. You will notice that nothing in Apple Pay nor the navigation bar will show up - you will only see your app's information.

```
print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)
```